# how to read mysql data using goroutine and channel in bulk

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm a newbee for golang, now need to read a big amount data in mysql, so I wanna use goroutine and channel to get data in high performance, but don't know how to avoid data duplication for each goroutine and make whole process stable. for instance, table schema is as below, I wanna get all records which `create_time` is smaller than `1000000000000000000`, I wanna create 10 goroutines and read data concurrently, each goroutine do some business logic, how to design codes? thank u

```
id content last_id create_time
```

Comment: Create N goroutines all listening to a channel. In a loop, read DB rows one by one and send them to the channel. Each goroutine processes one record. You need to provide more detail to decide what to do with the result of the computation.

Comment: I changed my question and given a roughly schema on my requirement, can help to review, thanks

Comment: Reading 1 record at a time is not computationally feasible. How can you point a solution to read one row at a time @BurakSerdar

Comment: @advayrajhansa, you fetch records from a DB one at a time, right?

Comment: if can read more than one is better, but only one is also acceptable

Comment: Obviously not, that will be in given batch size. DB transaction is resource heavy. better you get as much as rows in one transaction as possible and if needed, divide that further.

Comment: Reading rows from a DB result set one by one and letting the driver worry about batch size allows you to write readable code. A simple for-loop reads results, sends it down to a channel where multiple goroutine are waiting.

Comment: @Frank, all databases I know read in batches larger than one. Even if you read rows one by one, the driver fetches rows in batches.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a goroutine that would publish the data to your channel. Then you can add listener go routines to handle the published data.
This can be done as following:

Main :

```
const GoroutineCount = 10

type SomeData []int

func main() {
    ch := make(chan SomeData, 1)

    go PublishData(ch)

    for i := 0; i < GoroutineCount; i++ {
        go ProcessData(ch)
    }
}
```

For assumptions, I have used a simple slice of int as data. This can be slice of any struct as required.

Publish data to channel:

```
const ChunkSize = 1000

func PublishData(ch chan SomeData) {
    // Assume having 10000 records in result set
    // This has to come from db transaction
    res := make([]int, 10000)

    // split into chunks of 1000
    chunks := GetChunk(res)

    // write chunk data to channel
    for i := range chunks {
        ch <- chunks[i]
    }
}

func GetChunk(input SomeData) []SomeData {
    var result []SomeData

    boundary := len(input)
    index := 0
    for index = 0; boundary >= ChunkSize; index+=ChunkSize {
        boundary -= ChunkSize
        lastIndex := index+ChunkSize
        result = append(result, input[index:lastIndex])
    }
    boundary = len(input) % ChunkSize
    if boundary > 0 {
        lastIndex := index+ boundary
        result = append(result, input[index:lastIndex])
    }

    return result
}
```

Process individual chunks as :

```
func ProcessData(ch chan SomeData) {
    // Read single chunk
    res := <-ch

    // Process chunk data
    fmt.Printf("len %d\n", len(res))
}
```

Code on go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/X9Q991h6ru_n